# ScrollView scroll only one item at the time

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uiscrollview

I have a UIScrollView with 10 items, I want that each time that I scroll with my finger to right or left it will scroll only 1 item at the time. Even if i'm throwing the item fast as I can, only I item at the time.

The problem that I'm having that I have 2 items visible each time and also I don't really know how to do it, I just know that it's have to be done with

`- (void)scrollViewWillEndDragging:(UIScrollView *)scrollView withVelocity:(CGPoint)velocity targetContentOffset:(inout CGPoint *)targetContentOffset` and with `- (void)scrollViewDidEndDecelerating:(UIScrollView *)scrollView`

It looks like that when swiping:
[image: first scroller]
[image: third scroller]
[image: second scroller]

Thanks in advance..

Comment: What i get to know from your question, i think your problem will be solved if you enabled the scrollview paging property

Comment: what is the content size for scrollview you have set?

Comment: The contentSize is as the (size of item * items number) + (the space between the items * items number). And I don't think that paging is the right solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, paging is what will get that discrete scrolling, however, since you are displaying 2 pages at once, that will actually scroll both pages left or right.

You might try using a swipe gesture recognizer, detecting a left or right and then simply animate a fixed distance left or right. It's pretty simple to do.